# How to make Python try/except block cross-platform when it needs to handle a WindowsError exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, cross-platform

I have some code that looks like this:

```
        try:
            pid = subprocess.Popen(prog+args,
                    shell=False,
                    stdin=None,
                    stdout=None,
                    stderr=None,
                    close_fds=True,
                    creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS)
        except WindowsError as e:  
            if e.winerror == 2:     
                # @%$#%$ The system cannot find the file specified
                raise IOError("more meaningful message here")
            else:
                # log an exception
                raise
        except Exception as e:
            # This except block has no point except to be able to set a breakpoint
            raise
```

and it works fine on Windows but now I want to get it working on a Mac.

How can I make it cross-platform? Would it make sense to define a dummy `WindowsError` class if one does not exist?

I know I can switch from catching `WindowsError` to catching its superclass `OSError` in [the exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html), but at some point I need to check whether it's a `WindowsError` and handle that specially... and yet `WindowsError` doesn't exist on Mac or Linux.

(to clarify: this is legacy Python 2.7 code that I need to maintain, so Python 3 constructs are not an option for me at this time.)